# VBA Word: Difference between Font.TextColor and Font.ColorIndex?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that insert text. It was working well so far but... Now for some documents, I get an error 445 when it applies color.
Here is the code:

```
'Some code before that insert a first page with a different section and writes into the header
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
Selection.TypeParagraph

With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 14
    .Bold = True
    .Italic = False
    .TextColor = RGB(68, 114, 196)
End With

With Selection.ParagraphFormat
    .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .SpaceAfter = 6
End With

Selection.TypeText Text:="eReference file for work order: "
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="workorder"

Selection.TypeParagraph
```

I've notice that if I change "Selection.Font.TextColor = RGB(68, 114, 196)" and replace it by "Selection.Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkBlue", it works. Hence my question: What's the difference between the two? Why is there some document for which "Textcolor"doesn't work ?

Thank you !

Comment: .TextColor is readonly, so you can't set it to your desired color.

Comment: It works? You mean setting `Font.ColorIndex = RGB(68, 114, 196)` sets the color to RGB(64, 114, 196)? Or merely that it doesn't crash? Because given the nature of the `WdColorIndex` enum, I very much doubt that assigning it to a RGB value will give you the color you're giving it. I might be wrong though - I'm not very familiar with the Word object model.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I mean if I use 'Selection.Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkBlue' for example, it sets the color to Dark blue.

Comment: This code runs without issues for me in Word 2013.  Where are you setting the `Selection`?

Comment: @Comintern It seems that the code triggers the error randomly. It doesn't work on certain documents. But I cannot find any thing different in them. And I do not really set the `Selection`. I just don't know how to set the color without using it.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thank you for your help. I found the solution. The documents that caused problems were in "Compatibility mode". I convert the docs, and the macro works just fine. I don't really understand everything but it works...

Comment: I've also observed that using '.Color=...' instead of '.Textcolor=...' it also works. But, like you, I don't understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

[Font.TextColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194246.aspx) and [Font.ColorIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837918.aspx) are both documented on MSDN.

**ColorIndex**

> Returns or sets a **WdColorIndex** constant that represents the color for the specified font. Read/write.

[WdColorIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195343.aspx) is an enum that defines a number of predefined constants. Being an enum, its underlying value is a numeric value - a `Long` integer. When you assign it to the result of a `RGB` function call, you're giving it a `Long` integer, but not a `WdColorIndex` value - I very much doubt that the color you're getting matches the RGB value you've set.

**TextColor**

> Returns a **ColorFormat** object that represents the color for the specified font. Read-only.

A [ColorFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196880.aspx) object gives you much more control on how you want to format things. It's read-only because it's an *object* - that doesn't mean you can't change it (as in, *modify its state*), it only means you can't `Set` that object reference to something else... but you wouldn't need to do that anyway.

So instead of this:

> ```
> .TextColor = RGB(68, 114, 196)
> ```

You could do that:

```
 .TextColor.RGB = RGB(68, 114, 196)
```

[ColorFormat.RGB Property on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821171.aspx).

FWIW I'm getting run-time error 5843 when trying to assign a non-`WdColorIndex` enum value to `Font.ColorIndex`, so I'm confused with what you mean by "it works" - *especially* given that *IntelliSense* gives you the possible values for it:

[image: wdColorIndex constants]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I do understand the difference now, but unfortunately what you proposed doesn't work. I still have the same error. I really don't see what I could have done wrong...

Comment: @Pookye it works for me. Are you sure the error is being raised on the line you think it is?

Comment: @Pookye might be because you're working off the `Selection` - again I'm not all that familiar with MS-Word, but in Excel the `Selection` can be literally anything and coding against it is terrible practice that makes terribly frail code.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I ran it in Debug mode, put a Breakpoint and it stops at the line ".TextColor = RGB (68, 11, 196)". What I find really strange is that it works on some documents and not on others.

Comment: Type `?TypeName(Selection)` in the *immediate* / debug toolwindow (Ctrl+G), are you controlling the selection programmatically or letting it up to the user? Working against the current selection and assuming text is selected when the user selected, say, a shape, can lead to that kind of bugs.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm a newbie in VBA, I don't really know how to use the "Immediate" window... When I put my mouse on Selection after the bug, it says that "Selection = ♀". And actually, there is no text selected when I do run the macro. I simply add a new first page to the current document, write in the header and in the first page. The bug happens when I first set the font before writing the first page content.

Comment: Thank you for your help! it's kind of you. I guess I can just change the color of the text and use .ColorIndex... But I'm curious to know more about this strange behaviour :/

Comment: I suspect the root problem has to do with working against a `Selection` that you're not controlling. Again I don't work with Word, but there *must* be a much more robust way of programmatically accessing the document contents than through the `Selection`.

Comment: @Pookye BTW get yourself familiarized with the *immediate* toolwindow - it's your best friend when debugging. `Debug.Print` statements print to that window, and you can break anywhere and execute code against the current debugging context in that toolwindow. Learning to use the *immediate* pane should be your first priority once you know how to place a breakpoint.

Comment: Thank you ! I'll surely take a look at it. It's true that it is very important when debugging. And I totally agree with you on the Selection issue. I'll dig into it :)